# Is there any way mssql can notify my python application when any table or row has been updated?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, connection

I dont have much knowledge in dbs, but wanted to know if there is any technique by which when i update or insert a specific entry in a table, it should notify my python application to which i can then listen whats updated and then update that particular row, in the data stored in session or some temporary storage.
I need to send data filter and sort calls again n again, so i dont want to fetch whole data from sql, so i decided to keep it local, nd process it from there. But i was worried if in the mean time the db updates, and i could have been passing the same old data to filter requests.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you want something like "notification" in your program right?

Comment: Ya so that i can perform an update to my local’y saved data, or any other method on recieving such notification.. @M. Ali Öztürk

Answer (score 1):

1. rdbs only will be updated by your program's method or function sort of things.
2. you can just print console or log inside of yours.
3. if you want to track what updated modified deleted things,
4. you have to build a another program to able to track the logs for rdbs

thanks.